# 403 error on websocket handshake when using Java Spring boot Stomp app on Azure web apps

Tags: azure, web, websocket

I deployed a java spring boot with websocket app that works locally to the azure web app . When I get to the html page I get error

websocket.js:6 WebSocket connection to 'wss://ctiadapter.azurewebsites.net/ws/806/0qbqlnon/websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 403

My guess is because of reverse proxy azure web apps use but not sure how to fix or bypass it.

I appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Actually first, when you created an Azure WebApp and configured in `Application settings`, you need to enable `Web sockets` feature as below.

[image]

For trying to reproduce your issue, I downloaded the latest release of `spring-guides/gs-messaging-stomp-websocket` from https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-messaging-stomp-websocket/releases. And then, to build an executable jar file via `gradlew build` and upload it to the path `site/wwwroot` of my existing WebApp via Kudo console, and configure the `web.config` file to make it run.

[image]

Here is the content of `web.config`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
        </handlers>
        <!-- <httpPlatform processPath="%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" -->
        <httpPlatform processPath="D:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_181\bin\java.exe"
                      arguments="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dserver.port=%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT% -jar &quot;%HOME%\site\wwwroot\gs-messaging-stomp-websocket-0.1.0.jar&quot;">
        </httpPlatform>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Next, I got the same issue with yours, when I access `https://<my webapp name>.azurewebsites.net` and click the `Connect` button to establish a websocket connection with server.

[image]

I noticed there is the `websocket` request use `wss://` with SSL. So I tried to access `http://<my webapp name>.azurewebsites.net` to do the same operations, it works unexpectedly.

[image]

I searched and researched for it and the sample source code, I think there is missing Spring Security WebSocket Support in this sample. You can refer to the old spring blog [Preview Spring Security WebSocket Support](https://spring.io/blog/2014/08/21/preview-spring-security-websocket-support) and follow the Spring Security document about [WebSocket Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/html/websocket.html) to fix it. There are two personal GitHub repos [BijanVan/Spring-Boot-Websocket-Sample](https://github.com/BijanVan/Spring-Boot-Websocket-Sample/) and [rstoyanchev/spring-websocket-portfolio](https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-websocket-portfolio) which all use `org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.socket.AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer` to support WebSocket with SSL.